# How to map subquery in stored procedure in EF Core

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

We have the following models (shortenend for brevity)

```
public class Patient 
{
    public int Id {get; set;
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; } = new List<Address>();
}

public class Address 
{
    public int PatientId {get; set;
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

We like to map the results of a stored procedure ( a list of patients with their addresses) to them using EF.

```
select  
    p.* ,
    (select a.street from Addresses as a where a.PatientId = p.id) as addresses
from 
    Patients as p
where 
    ... (a set of clauses and joins to limit the list to the desired patients)
```

Without the extra select to get the addresses all works fine, well, except we do not get the addresses.

We get the error :

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not return a list into an column in `SQL`. you can join data with dash `-` and store in a column like this and you can **Split** `AddressData` in `c#` by `-` and store in a list.

```sql
select  
    p.* ,
    AddressData = COALESCE(STUFF
    (
            (
                select ' - ' + a.street from Addresses as a where a.PatientId = p.id
                   FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1,2, N''
    ), N'')
from 
    Patients as p
where 
    ... (a set of clauses and joins to limit the list to the desired patients)
```

```cs
public class Patient 
{
    public int Id {get; set;
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string AddressData { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses 
    {
        get 
        {
            return AddressData.Split('-').ToList().Select(a => new Address 
              {
                   Street = a
              }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```